# How to convert a string to an email address

Tags: string, email

I was looking at some job postings online and came across one that had an extra credit blurb. It says

`Extra credit: (Convert the below string to the email address)
636f64792e73696e676572406f6e6563616c6c2e636f6d`

I was curious on how to convert this string to an email address

I'm not sure if this will help or not, but here is the job posting:
`http://spokane.craigslist.org/tch/5505150791.html`

Comment: hexadecimally encoded bytes, paste it here: http://www.convertstring.com/EncodeDecode/HexDecode

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks for the help!